# Spring Data JPA: Implementing Custom Repository Behavior with Specifications

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to create a Spring Data JPA repository with custom behavior, and implement that custom behavior using [Specification](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html)s. I have gone through the [Spring Data JPA documentation for implementing custom behavior in a single repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) to set this up, except there is no example of using a Spring Data [Specification](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) from within a custom repository. How would one do this, if even possible?

I do not see a way to inject something into the custom implementation that takes a specification. I thought I would be tricky and inject the CRUD repository portion of the repository into the custom portion, but that results in a circular instantiation dependency.

I am not using QueryDSL. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the primary source for inspiration could be how `SimpleJpaRepository` handles specifications. The key spots to have a look at are:

- [`SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(…)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/1.7.1.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L484) - it's basically creating a `CriteriaQuery` and bootstraps a select using a JPA `Root`. Whether the latter applies to your use case is already up to you. I think the former will apply definitely.
- [`SimpleJpaRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria(…)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/1.7.1.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L528) - it basically uses the artifacts produced in `getQuery(…)` (i.e. the `Root` and the `CriteriaQuery`) and applies the given `Specification` to exactly these artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

this is not using Specification, so not sure if it's relevant to you, but one way that I was able to inject custom behavior is as follows,

1. Basic structure: as follows

   i. create a generic interface for the set of entity classes which are modeled after a generic parent entity. Note, this is optional. In my case I had a need for this hierarchy, but it's not necessary

   ```
   public interface GenericRepository<T> {

   // add any common methods to your entity hierarchy objects, 
   // so that you don't have to repeat them in each of the children entities
   // since you will be extending from this interface
   }
   ```

   ii. Extend a specific repository from generic (step 1) and JPARepository as

   ```
   public interface MySpecificEntityRepository extends GenericRepository<MySpecificEntity>, JpaRepository<MySpecificEntity, Long> {

   // add all methods based on column names, entity graphs or JPQL that you would like to 
   // have here in addition to what's offered by JpaRepository
   }
   ```

   iii. Use the above repository in your service implementation class

   2. Now, the Service class may look like this,

      ```
      public interface GenericService<T extends GenericEntity, ID extends Serializable> {
         // add specific methods you want to extend to user
      }
      ```
   3. The generic implementation class can be as follows,

      ```
      public abstract class GenericServiceImpl<T extends GenericEntity, J extends JpaRepository<T, Long> & GenericRepository<T>> implements GenericService<T, Long> {

      // constructor takes in specific repository
          public GenericServiceImpl(J genericRepository) {
             // save this to local var
          } 
        // using the above repository, specific methods are programmed

      }
      ```
   4. specific implementation class can be

      ```
      public class MySpecificEntityServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<MySpecificEntity, MySpecificEntityRepository> implements MySpecificEntityService {

          // the specific repository is autowired
          @Autowired
          public MySpecificEntityServiceImpl(MySpecificEntityRepository genericRepository) {
               super(genericRepository);
               this.genericRepository = (MySpecificEntityRepository) genericRepository;
           }
       }
      ```